# Use sql server Convert Function to convert hijri to gregorian date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have simple table on my `sql server` and in my table have a date field,and into date field save a `hijri date`,i want use the `sql server` convert function to convert `hijri date` to `gregorian date`.
how can i do this?

i use this query in sql server:

```
update k
set time=CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),101)
```

and i insert this `"1392/4/21"` in time field ,and when convert sql server return this `"2014/11/5"`,when i use online date convertor,and insert this `"2014/11/5"`,convert date is `"1393/2/14"` !!is this the correct resualt?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample how you could do it:

```
select convert(datetime, value, 131)
from (
    values ('13/01/1436  9:54:59:767AM')
    ) samples(value)
```

There are several blogs about this, likethis one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wael/archive/2007/04/29/sql-server-hijri-hijra-dates.aspx

and this one:
http://raresql.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/sql-server-how-to-convert-gregorian-dates-to-hijri-date-with-formatting/