# How to get year of character hijri date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, datepart

I searched and tried many examples unable to solve my hijri date is like,

```
19/07/1440
```

I tried this query

```
 SELECT TOP 200   
     DATEPART(YEAR, EndDateHejri)
 FROM 
     student
```

but I'm getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I'm unable to solve error - hoping for your suggestions

Comment: We need to know the structure of your table.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `EndDateHejri` column in the `Student` table?

Comment: its type is nvarchar

Comment: https://raresql.com/2013/05/08/sql-server-how-to-convert-gregorian-dates-to-hijri-date-with-formatting/

Comment: Are they all in the format `00/00/yyyy`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749403/use-sql-server-convert-function-to-convert-hijri-to-gregorian-date

Comment: Try not to save the Hijri date as datetime and also try not to store the date just as UTC otherwise you must convert each datetime to Hijri by specific time zone difference and daylight time

Comment: @Mat i want year part of Hijri not to convert it to georgian

Comment: @Larnu yes it is

Comment: i tried it by "SELECT top 200  year( convert(datetime, EndDateHejri, 131)) from student"  but giving 2019 i need hijri

Comment: @syedmohsin - I know, but `DATEPART()` requires a `DATETIME` data typed parameter, and `DATETIME` is implicitly gregorian.  In short, you ***can't*** use `DATEPART()` to get the year from a Hijri date.

Answer (score 2):

I bit of Google-Fu and format 131 should help you convert Hijri dates into Gregorian Dates...

```
DECLARE @hijri DATETIME = CONVERT(datetime, ' 7/05/1421 12:14:35:727PM', 131)

SELECT @hijri
```

Unfortunately, all the date functions *(`DATEPART()`, `DATENAME()`, even `DATEADD()`, etc)* are all based on manipulating Gregorian dates.  So you can't use them.

So, you're forced to use string manipulation.

```
DECLARE @hijri DATETIME = CONVERT(datetime, ' 7/05/1421 12:14:35:727PM', 131)

SELECT @hijri

SELECT DATEPART(year, @hijri)
-- Gives 2000 :(

SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @hijri, 131), 4)
-- Gives 1421 :)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=901209ae0cdcf38cdcdea8afad4fd034

Comment: My first thought was the right(...,4) but I wasn't sure there would be time values as well  +1

Answer (score 2):

Posting a different answer. As the OP is only after the year part, and they've stated that it's always in the format `00/00/yyyy` why not just use `RIGHT`? So:

```
SELECT RIGHT(EndDateHejri,4) as HejriYear;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried answer [@Vishnu Chandel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488314/8370334) it's working for me .

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,CONVERT(datetime2(0),convert(VARCHAR,EndDateHejri),103))
```

And full code is :

```
SELECT TOP 200   
   SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,CONVERT(datetime2(0),convert(VARCHAR,EndDateHejri),103)) as year
 FROM 
     student
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code to get the correct output.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,CONVERT(datetime2(0),convert(VARCHAR,EndDateHejri),103));
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 200
CAST(FORMAT(EndDateHejri,'yyyy','ar') as int) [EndDateHejriYear]
FROM
student